# ggplot2: Multiple trend lines in a faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, trendline

I'm trying to add two trend lines to the data plotted in my faceted plot for two different depths `(Road=color)`. `Geom_smooth` works to generate the first plot`(pred_new2)` with trend line, but as soon as I add `facet_wrap` - the plot is generated, but without any trend lines/smoothing and without any error.

```
pred_new$Site <- factor(pred_new$Site, 
                        levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))

pred_new2 <- ggplot(pred_new, aes(x = No_cars, y = Site, color = Road)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = No_cars, y = Site, color = Road), method = "lm")

pred_new3 <- pred_new2 + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = No_cars - standerror, xmax = No_cars + standerror))

pred_new4 <- pred_new3 + 
  facet_wrap(~ Days, scales = "free_x") + 
  ylab("Site") + 
  xlab("No_cars") + 
  theme_classic()
pred_new4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pred_new = structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                             8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                                             6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                             4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
                                           .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"), 
                                           class = "factor"), 
                          Days = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                           .Label = c("Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), 
                                           class = "factor"),
                          Road = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L), 
                                           .Label = c("east", "west"), 
                                           class = "factor"), 
                          No_cars = c(15.266427, 8.323348, 8.368608, 9.747807, 7.976356, 8.5684, 6.604537, 
                                      3.812109, 6.719904, 4.799487, 4.996091, 4.796, 4.991479, 4.525789, 
                                      5.115136, 4.939559, 4.783792, 4.185007, 3.857553, 3.095228, 2.890727, 
                                      3.132784, 3.352974, 3.42561, 2.900284, 2.35416, 2.889976, 17.266427, 
                                      10.323348, 10.368608, 11.747807, 9.976356, 10.5684, 8.604537, 5.812109, 
                                      8.719904, 6.799487, 6.996091, 6.796, 6.991479, 6.525789, 7.115136, 
                                      6.939559, 6.783792, 6.185007, 5.857553, 5.095228, 4.890727, 5.132784, 
                                      5.352974, 5.42561, 4.900284, 4.35416, 4.889976), 
                          standerror = c(1.7108483, 0.8175014, 0.6365042, 0.7171749, 0.9978123, 0.9881427, 
                                         0.9215597, 0.6365042, 1.6303975, 0.404129, 0.1934362, 0.1503158, 
                                         0.1694848, 0.2362161, 0.2337497, 0.2180687, 0.1604379, 0.3902528, 
                                         0.3276444, 0.1568268, 0.1218673, 0.1374084, 0.1915103, 0.1895107, 
                                         0.1767974, 0.1300738, 0.3163943, 1.7108483, 0.8175014, 0.6365042, 
                                         0.7171749, 0.9978123, 0.9881427, 0.9215597, 0.6365042, 1.6303975, 
                                         0.404129, 0.1934362, 0.1503158, 0.1694848, 0.2362161, 0.2337497,
                                         0.2180687, 0.1604379, 0.3902528, 0.3276444, 0.1568268, 0.1218673, 
                                         0.1374084, 0.1915103, 0.1895107, 0.1767974, 0.1300738, 0.3163943)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Elle Blank. I highly recommend you format your code as code. It makes it easier for people to read and therefore easier for them to help you. I've done it for you in this question.

Comment: Thanks @JamesJones first time asking a q!

Comment: Try posting your data, or a minimal toy dataset sufficient for reproducing the issue. One possibility is that adding facets mean there aren't enough points per facet to draw the fitted line, but hard to say without seeing the data.

Comment: @arvi1000 Ive added the data in please see above

Comment: theres 9 points for each facet

Comment: @ElleBlank: please use `dput(pred_new)` to share data. See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: For each level of `Days` you have only one observation in each category of `Road` (`east` or `west`) and since `Site` is factor, there cannot be any trend.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks Adela. I wanted to plot the trend of no_cars across the different sites.. is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you swap the axes. To include trend you need numeric values for `Site`, so I include `as.numeric(Site)` in `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pred_new, aes(x = as.numeric(Site), y = No_cars, color = Road)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = No_cars - standerror, ymax = No_cars + standerror)) +
  xlab("Site") + 
  # this will recode your x-axis
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:9, labels = LETTERS[1:9]) +
  facet_wrap(~ Days, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme_classic() +
  # you can swap x and y axes with coord_flip()
  coord_flip()
```

Is this desired output?

[image]

In case you really want `Site` on the y-axis, you can simply flip x and y axes:

```
ggplot(pred_new, aes(y = as.numeric(Site), x = No_cars, color = Road)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = No_cars - standerror, xmax = No_cars + standerror)) +
  ylab("Site") + 
  # this will recode your y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:9, labels = LETTERS[1:9]) +
  facet_wrap(~ Days, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Adela! This is pretty much exactly what I was after - 
however I was hoping to have `Site` on the y axis - as the `site`s are shared across the different `day`, whereas the scale of the `no_cars` is different depending what `day`. If I made site a numerical variable - is it possible to change the y axis to read the different sites, rather than numbers.

Thanks, 
Elle

Comment: I added axes flip into the answer. Hope this helps.